# Javascript code display text

Tags: javascript, text, canvas

Have code for a rectangle with a line through it, I would like to display text under the rectangle. How do I add this into my code? Or can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<canvas id="main" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

 <script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById("main");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "#008000";
context.rect(0,0,300,300);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = "blue";
context.lineCap = "round";
context.moveTo( 50, 150);
context.lineTo (250, 150);
context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw text using [`fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#fillText%28%29):

```
context.fillText("Hello, world!", 50, 50);
```

For more information, see [this article on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas).

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that but tried doing it with a separate canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the [`fillText`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_filltext.asp) function:

```
context.font="30px Arial";
context.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```